# How To Find ScrollViewer Inside of WPF ContentControl?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

WPF 4.5 / C#

I've got an app where I have several WPF Windows each utilizing this custom content control. I use it in the XAML like this:

```html
<ContentControl Name="myControl" Style="{StaticResource ReservedSpaceScrollBar}"
```

In the code behind, I need to be able to access the ScrollViewer inside, so I can call .ScrollToTop()

I've tried this, but it doesn't work:

((ScrollViewer)this.myControl.FindName("Scroll")).ScrollToTop();

...but .FindName doesn't find the ScrollViewer. What am I doing wrong? How make this work?

The XAML for the Style is below...

```html
   <Style TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}" x:Key="ReservedSpaceScrollBar">
      <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
      <Setter Property="Template">
         <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
               <ScrollViewer PanningMode="Both" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" x:Name="Scroll" FocusVisualStyle="{x:Null}">
                  <Grid>
                     <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                     </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                     <ContentPresenter />
                     <Border Width="{x:Static SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarWidth}" x:Name="Placeholder" Grid.Column="1" />
                  </Grid>
               </ScrollViewer>
               <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                  <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility, ElementName=Scroll}" Value="Visible">
                     <Setter TargetName="Placeholder" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                  </DataTrigger>
               </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
         </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>
   </Style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into the [VisualTreeHelper](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.visualtreehelper%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Using that class you can look into children of elements; for example:

```
var childCount = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(this.myControl);

for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++)
{
    var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(this.myControl, i);

    if (child.GetValue(NameProperty).ToString() == "Scroll")
    {
        ((ScrollViewer)child).ScrollToTop();
    }
}
```